# Is there any other better way to get and compare database credentials with java?

Tags: java, mysql, database, authentication, passwords

I am trying to create a simple login system with java using mySQl database.

I have stored user ID and password in a database table.
I've come up with a way to login which seems to work well but i am not sure if it's the right way to do it, as i couldn't find any online source for login systems.

My steps are :

1. getting input from the user (user ID and password).
2. Using the fetch() method that i created to iterate through the table and finding this specific ID.
3. If it's found, get the password and balance from the table and store them in variables.
4. Finally compare the password that i previously got from the database and stored in a variable with the password inputed from the user.

**I am well aware that storing passwords in plain text is a big security hole, but for now i am just trying to learn the way to use the data from the DB in my java program**

This is my code:

```
public class firstjava extends Database {

    public static int UID = 0;
    public static String password;
    public static int BAL;
    public static String upassword;

    static void fetch(int userid) throws SQLException {
        String query = "SELECT * FROM Persons";
        Statement st = con.createStatement();

        ResultSet rs = st.executeQuery(query);

        while (rs.next()) {
            int ID = rs.getInt("pid");
            if (ID == UID) {
                password = rs.getString("password");
                BAL = rs.getInt("balance");
            }

        }
        if (upassword.equals(password)) {
            System.out.println("you are now logged in");
        } else {
            System.out.println("incorrect password");
        }
        st.close();
    }

    public static void menu() throws IOException, SQLException {
        Scanner atm = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("enter your account number");
        UID = atm.nextInt();
        System.out.println("enter your account password");
        upassword = atm.next();
        fetch(UID);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException, SQLException {
        Database db = new Database();
        try {
            db.connect();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        menu();
        db.close();
    }
}
```

Comment: *Using the fetch() method that i created to iterate through the table and finding this specific ID* - This can be a heavy operation, especially if you have thousands of users (= thousands of iterations). Instead, use the `WHERE` clause to select users with a specific username, this way the while loop will execute at most 1 time (given that you don't have duplicates). You could also filter by username *and* password, this way you'll have a single query that checks if the user exists and the password matches.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion @BackSlash i executed SELECT WHERE query using my result set and used an if statement to check if my result set is true then got the password.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can directly pass userId as parameter to your query and fetch password and balance from DB Table then you should compare password with user entered password.

```
static void fetch(int userid) throws SQLException
{
    PreparedStatement ps = null;
    ResultSet rs = null;

    String query = "SELECT * FROM Persons where pid = ?";
    PreparedStatement ps = con.prepareStatement(query);
    ps.setInt(1,userid);
    rs = ps.executeQuery(); //instantiate rs with executed query

    while(rs.next()) {
        password = rs.getString("password");
        BAL = rs.getInt("balance");
    }   
    if(upassword.equals(password)) {
        System.out.println("you are now logged in");
    } else {
        System.out.println("incorrect password");
    }
    rs.close();
    ps.close();    
}
```

Comment: Welcome @Jix Sas
Did it work for you? I mean did you find that it is the answer which you were looking for?

Answer (score 0):

"If I have been able to see further, it was only because I stood on the shoulders of giants."

Here is the giant:

https://spring.io

You'll find something like:

```
Optional<User> r = userRepo.findByName(name);
BCryptPasswordEncoder passwordEncoder = new BCryptPasswordEncoder();
if (passwordEncoder.matches(password, user.getPassword())) {
   // ...
}
```

Comment: *for now i am just trying to learn the way to use the data from the DB in my java program* - "use spring" here is not a good suggestion IMO, especially if the OP is a beginner.

Comment: @BackSlash is right, but thank you for the suggestion i might use spring in the future.